# facebook upload photo

Tags: php, facebook, upload

I'm new to the facebook api, and i have a small issue.
I'm trying to upload a picture to an album of an user. For this i'm using a PHP script i've found here, on stack overflow :

```
    $app_id = xxx;
$app_secret = "xxx";
$my_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/test.php";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}


$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
    . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

//upload photo
$file= 'test.png';
$args = array(
   'message' => 'Photo from application',
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

print_r($args);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/2038278/photos?access_token='.$access_token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//returns the photo id
print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

But the result is :

> Array ( [message] => Photo from
>   application [test.png] =>
>   @/[mypath]/test.png ) Array ( [error]
>   => Array ( [type] => OAuthException [message] => Error validating
>   application. ) )

What does this mean ? Do i need to have extended permissions for my app ?wich of them ?
i gave it acces to basic and user_photos

Thank you very much!

---

the second script

$app_id = "xxx";
    $app_secret = "xxx";
    $my_url = "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/test.php";

```
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=user_photos" ;

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}


$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
    . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);









$token = $access_token;

//upload photo
$file= 'test.png';
$args = array(
'message' => 'Photo from application',
);
$args[basename($file)] = '@' . realpath($file);

$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token='.$token;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

print_r(json_decode($data,true));
```

Comment: hi do you want to upload a photo in the existing album of a user?

Comment: hi! for testing yes, that's what i tried, but what i need is to automatically create an album for my app

Comment: it does say 'error validating application' - are you sure the problem isn't with your facebook app itself? maybe it's incorrectly configured, or you're not passing the right keys to facebook for the initial authentication step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need your application to ask for the permission called `publish_stream`. There is also another permission called `photo_upload`, but as I understand that is considered old (but may still work)

Comment: thanks! i've tried with both permisions, both nothing, the same exception

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at some other tutorial on how to upload a picture using Facebook Graph API: http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/

Answer (score 1):

my dear when ever you upload any photo from your application to facebook, Facebook automatically create an album with the name of your application. You dont need to do any thing. Just upload any photo from your application and then goes to your profile, see all albums then you will see that facebook has created an album with the name of your application and your uploaded photo is residing in it.

Comment: i know this and for this i've allready built another script that would automatically create the album. But it's the same situation - it doesn't work. I'll add it to the question, maybe i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would not go that way if i were you. The cURL method has proven to be, for me at least, a tad too complicated. These are the steps that has to be taken, below you can see a link to a great **recent** blog post about this exact issue:

1. Get user's `user_photos` and `publish_stream` (not necessary, but good for future development).
2. Create album on behalf of user, which will contain the photo you wish to upload.
3. Get the album id of the album you just created.
4. Specify the photo's parameters: The message to go along with it, the location of the file on the server, and a bunch of other stuff you can look up in [this docs reference about publishing photos (bottom of page)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/).
5. Upload the photo with the given parameters.

[Dai Pratt's **excellent** tutorial on photo uploading via the **New** Graph API](http://daipratt.co.uk/facebook-api-upload-photo/)

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** There is a serious flaw in the script above-it does not check if the album exists already, in case you want to upload multiple photos on behalf of the user. It's important you store the user's id and the album id you created in a database, so you can query it each time the user wishes o upload an image, and create or not create an album accordingly.

**EDIT**: And now, after I've posted, I see the exact link in a comment here. Anyhow-hope this helps:)