# Why cannot I post a new photo with application token (and publish_share permission) facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a photo for my application user on behalf of the application (by app token) according to the link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

"App access tokens can also be used to publish content to Facebook on behalf of a user who has granted a publishing permission to your application."

But I cannot make it because I'm getting an error:
{"error":{"message":"A user access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":102}}

It's though I already have an approval for "publish_stream".

The code:

```
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

Is there any way to post a photo through application token?

Comment: Can you put your code sample?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850296/facebook-upload-photo

Comment: Check to ensure the access_token is valid and persisted when posting. You can run it through the Debugger tool to see if it's valid, and what kind of permissions it has. Also, try removing the album id and posting directly to see if that works or not. Similar Q/As here - http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/6260085/1628782 and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ and https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Comment: Thanks for your response but I still have the same problem. I will try to make it clear. I want to post a photo for user who already added the permission publish_stream in the past with application token (not user token). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try with publish_stream

regards

Answer (score 0):

or publish_actions

looks better cause the user doesn't have to have a separate page/window where he could click on "skip"

Comment: I already tried publish_actions but I don't think it helps. I'm not sure that I understand your meaning.